# How to clip a tensor in Keras, with a different clipping value for each subtensor?

Tags: python, keras, clipping

I have a 4d tensor `W` (the kernel of a 2d convolution) and a 1d array/tensor `H` specifying the clipping values for each filter. This means that I have

```py
len(H) == W.shape[-1]
```

and I want all elements of `W[:,:,:,i]` to be clipped between `-H[i]` and `H[i]`.

I have looked at the [keras.backend.clip](https://keras.io/backend/#clip), which says you can specify the min and max values as tensors, but you cannot specify the axis. I would appreciate if anyone can show me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this inside some layer:

```
H = K.reshape(H, (1, 1, 1, -1))
topClip = K.minimum(H, W)
clipped = K.maximum(-H, topClip)
```

---

As commented by Diego Palacios, although `clip` accepts tensors, it accepts only tensors with 1 element.

Comment: Thank you! The first option works fine but the second does not. It seems that `K.clip` only accepts tensors with 1 element.